# UNIX `find` and specifying base directory

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to execute `find` on a specific directory in order to search for errors. The data files are stored in a directory (from root) of `/shared/Simulations/`. But nothing I do seems to be able to specify the directory to `find`. For example, see the following. Only the last line gets any results.

```
[/]$ cd shared
[shared]$ find "/shared/Simulations/" -nowarn 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -sl "NaN"
[shared]$ find "Simulations" -nowarn 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -sl "NaN"
[shared]$ find "./Simulations" -nowarn 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -sl "NaN"
[shared]$ find "./Simulations/" -nowarn 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -sl "NaN"
[shared]$ find ./Simulations -nowarn 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -sl "NaN"
[shared]$ find ./Simulations/ -nowarn 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -sl "NaN"
[shared]$ cd Simulations
[Simulations]$ find "." -nowarn 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -sl "NaN"
... a bunch of results, like I want ...
```

As you can see, specifying "." works fine, but nothing I do works. Specifying anything but "." prevents it from finding anything at all.

Any ideas?

**SOLVED**: spaces in the directory names, use `-print0` and `xargs -0` as in:

```
find "directory" -nowarn -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 grep -sl "NaN"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've thrown the error messages away, you don't know what `find` is complaining about (if it complains about anything).

Most probably, `find` is not following a symlink; it doesn't by default. If `/shared/Simulations` is a symbolic link to somewhere, then the behaviour is explicable.  Otherwise, I'm at a loss.

```
find /shared/Simulations/.
```

should work if that's the problem; it follows the symlink before it starts searching.

Comment: I tried without the stderr redirect and without the -nowarn and there are no errors or warnings. However, I did find the problem. If any subdirectory has spaces, it fails. In reality, the Simulations folder is something more complex, with spaces... so... yeah. I need to use `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0 ...` to make it work.

Comment: I'll accept your answer anyway since it's the only one. :)

Comment: Well, yes; if there are spaces in the paths, then `xargs` makes a meal of it since it breaks names at spaces, tabs, newlines, etc (white space, generally).  But there's no way to guess that it is the problem from the data in the question.  It's always tricky sanitizing a question — in this case, you accidentally removed the feature that caused the problem.